# I want to display data inserted into database after submission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a generator script, it basically generates random tokens and stores them in a MySQL database. Several people will use it and what I want to do it basically show the generated tokens that were just generated on the generation page so that when they generate tokens and they're all mixed up with others they can easily copy the ones they generated without having to go through the whole table of everyone's tokens.

I have put the entire form and script here, the submission part works perfect, just wondering about that extra feature and if it would be a possibility.

```
<?php 
function randString($length, $charset='ABCEFGHJKLMNPRTUVWXY23456789' ) 
{ 
    $str='' ; 
    $count=strlen($charset); 
    while ($length--) { 
        $str.=$charset[mt_rand(0, $count - 1) ]; 
    } 
    return $str; 
} 

if (isset($_POST[ 'create'])) { 
    $token_semi_quantity=0 ; 
    $token_combo=$ _POST[ 'howmany']; 
    $seller=$_POST[ 'seller']; 
    while ($token_semi_quantity < $token_combo) { 
        $token=randString(4) . "-" . randString(4) . "-" . randString(4); 
        $token_semi_quantity++; 
        $token_info=$_POST[ 'tokeninfo']; 
        $token_explode=e xplode( ',', $token_info); 
        $token_time=$token_explode[0]; 
        $token_desc=$token_explode[1]; 
        $NowDateTime=date( "Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
        // Log dat shit 
        $WhoGenDatToken=$userRow[ 'username'] . ' Generated Token <b>' . $token . '</b> at ' . date( "m-d-Y h:i") . ' CST.'; 
        $gen_token=new CONNECT; 
        $insert_token=( "INSERT INTO `tokens`
                            (`id`, `token`, `time`, `generatedby`, 
                            `timegenerated`, `used`, `seller`,
                             `description`)
                        VALUES ('NULL', :generatetokenVal, 
                                :generatetokentimeVal, :generatetokenadminName, 
                                :generateDateTime, '0', 
                                :generatetokenSeller, :generatetokenDesc);
                        INSERT INTO `admin_act` (`activity`)
                         VALUES(:WhoGenDatTokenDen)"); 
        $stmt=$gen_token->runQuery($insert_token); 
        $stmt->execute(Array( ':generatetokenVal' => $token, 
                            ':generatetokentimeVal' => $token_time, 
                            ':generatetokenadminName' => $adminName, 
                            ':generateDateTime' => $NowDateTime, 
                            ':generatetokenSeller' => $seller, 
                            ':generatetokenDesc' => $token_desc, 
                            ':WhoGenDatTokenDen' => $WhoGenDatToken )); 

    } 
} 
?>
<!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
<div class="page-content-wrap">
<div class="row">
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-tags"></span>&nbsp;<?php
echo $xblsname; ?> Token Generator</h2>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default tabs">
            <div class="panel-body tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-first">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h3><?php
echo $xblsname; ?> Token Generator</h3>
                        <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">How Many?</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control select" name="howmany">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                        <option value="13">13</option>
                                        <option value="14">14</option>
                                        <option value="15">15</option>
                                        <option value="16">16</option>
                                        <option value="17">17</option>
                                        <option value="18">18</option>
                                        <option value="19">19</option>
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="21">21</option>
                                        <option value="22">22</option>
                                        <option value="23">23</option>
                                        <option value="24">24</option>
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="26">26</option>
                                        <option value="27">27</option>
                                        <option value="28">28</option>
                                        <option value="29">29</option>
                                        <option value="30">30</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="help-block">Choose how many to generate</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Token Type</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="tokeninfo" id="tokeninfo">
                                        <option value="1,1 Day Server Time">1 Day Server Only</option>
                                        <option value="3,3 Days Server Only">3 Days Server Only</option>
                                        <option value="7,1 Week Server Only">1 Week Server Only</option>
                                        <option value="14,2 Weeks Server Only">2 Weeks Server Only</option>
                                        <option value="31,1 Month Server Only">1 Month Server Only</option>
                                        <option value="110,1 Day with GTA Menu">1 Day with GTA Menu</option>
                                        <option value="111,3 Days with GTA Menu">3 Days with GTA Menu</option>
                                        <option value="112,1 Week with GTA Menu">1 Week with GTA Menu</option>
                                        <option value="113,2 Weeks with GTA Menu">2 Weeks with GTA Menu</option>
                                        <option value="114,1 Month with GTA Menu">1 Month with GTA Menu</option>
                                        <option value="999,Custom Token 1">Custom Token 1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="help-block">Choose token value</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Seller</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="seller">
                                        <?php // Don 't change the options here - do it in includes/settings.php -JohnC
if (!empty($seller1)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller1 . "\">" . $seller1 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller2)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller2 . "\">" . $seller2 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller3)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller3 . "\">" . $seller3 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller4)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller4 . "\">" . $seller4 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller5)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller5 . "\">" . $seller5 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller6)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller6 . "\">" . $seller6 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller7)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller7 . "\">" . $seller7 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller8)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller8 . "\">" . $seller8 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller9)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller9 . "\">" . $seller9 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller10)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller10 . "\">" . $seller10 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller11)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller11 . "\">" . $seller11 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller12)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller12 . "\">" . $seller12 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller13)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller13 . "\">" . $seller13 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller14)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller14 . "\">" . $seller14 . "</option>";
if (!empty($seller15)) print "<option value=\"" . $seller15 . "\">" . $seller15 . "</option>";
?>
                                                </select>
                                                    <span class="help-block">Choose seller</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                            <button name = "create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Generate Token(s) <span class="fa fa-magic fa-right"></span></button>
                                            </form>
                                            </div>




                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                           
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Comment: If you can read it, then just maybe, **you can debug it**

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I tried to reformat the code, but there are too many odd spaces in places that would probably cause compilation errors, so I gave up

Comment: I used a "beautifier" to try and make it fit here correctly as manually adding 4 spaces (which I never use) is a task when dealing with much code. But yea, I know it does not look right here, but it looks fine in Notepad++ FYI. 

I might delete the question as I think I'm on to the answer already anyway

Comment: First Question: Is your `runQuery()` method setup to do Multiple Queries?

Comment: I got the problem solved myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it, I simply checked if the data was sent and echo'd $token in there and the token was displayed nicely. Only works when you generate one token, if you generate more than one, only one is displayed, I'm playing around with a foreach argument but it seems to fail too. lol oh well, I guess I gotta try harder ha

Comment: just store your tokens into some temp variable `$generatedtokens[] = $token;` and output that at the end.

Comment: @Jakumi   I thought they were already stored in $token, lol.

Comment: if you echo them inside the (same) loop, then you're correct. but you said, only one is displayed (assuming it being the last one) implies, you display it outside the loop

Comment: Yea, but I'm somewhere else down the page lol, that is why then. lol

Comment: Just to be sure, I echo'd $token in the loop and indeed it does show all the tokens. What exactly is needed to use this var outside the loop (to list all tokens)?

Comment: that's why you store them while you're inside the loop (like i showed for example) and then use that stored var later to output it (with foreach or whatever)

Comment: I got it working, yea thanks.

Comment: <?php
          if (isset($_POST['create'])){
           echo'<div class =" col-md-6 pull-right"><h3>Tokens Generated</h3><br>';
          if((isset($_POST['create']) && ($insert_token && $stmt->rowCount())) >0){
           
            foreach ($generatedtokens as $tokens){
           echo ''.$tokens.'<br>';
           }
           if (isset($_POST['create'])){
            echo '</div>';
            }
           }
          }
          ?>

LOL, so much to make sure it displays correctly, haha.
Thanks for your help bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop, store the token into an array/collection/list

```
// inside while loop, after $token = ...
$generatedtoken[] = $token;
```

then wherever you want to show/list them:

```
foreach($generatedtoken as $token) {
    echo $token; // some markup maybe added
}
```

appending to a var that's not considered an array (yet) is probably dirty, so before the `if` or somewhere appropriate, instantiate the array.

```
$generatedtoken = array();
```

Comment: So, if I used $generatetoken[] = Array()

I would be able to echo the entire items outside the loop like;

`foreach($generatedtoken as $token) {
    echo $token['token'] . '-' . $token['desc'];`

Something like that?

Comment: if that `Array()` would contain those keys, then yes.

Comment: Got it working perfectly.

     `$generatedtokens[]  = Array(
            'token' => $token,
            'desc' => $token_desc);`

etc. Better than the VAR as it lets you get more of the data.
Thanks again buddy.